# error in appliaction name, mipmap/ic_launcher, normal theme and launcher theme

Tags: flutter, dart, build.gradle

why every new flutter app I make have this error in error in application name, mipmap/ic_launcher, normal theme and launcher theme in app level build.gradle
[here's pic of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0bWd.png)

Comment: Do you get errors while running those apps?

Comment: It runs normally when it's a simple activity but I'm trying to run apps from GitHub and they have the same errors 
and these errors are causing problems for example error in putting  ic launcher icon

Comment: If every project have the same error it is probably an IDE problem, I got them all the time in Android Studio, but the projects have no problem whatsoever. That is why I use VS Code most of the time unless I want to use **icon generator** in Android studio.